# how to check the continuity of following function

Tags: analysis

Consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by 
$$f(x,y)=(7x+x^4,3x+4y+y^4) $$
then how check the continuity of function at $(0,0)$  determine directional derivative at $(0,0).$

Comment: What did you try on your own? Where did you find difficulties?

Comment: The components are polynomial. Thus continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- A function with domain $\mathbb{R}^m$ is continuous at a point if and only if each component function is continuous at that point.  In this case, the function is continuous at $(0,0)$ if and only if the functions $7x + x^4$ and $3x + 4y + y^4$ from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous at $(0,0)$.
- What can you say about functions that are just polynomials in $x$ and $y$?

You also seem to want to compute the directional derivative, but I don't know where to help you here since you haven't given any idea of where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

$||f(x,y)-f(0,0)||=\sqrt{(x^4+7x)^2+(y^4+4y+3x)^2}\le \sqrt{x^2(x^3+7)^2+(y^2+x^2)((y^3+4)^2+3^2)}\le \sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(x^3+7)^2+(x^2+y^2)((y^3+4)^2+3^2)}\le  \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sqrt{((x^3+7)^2+(y^3+4)^2+3^2)}<||(x,y)-(0,0)||M$

Note that $\exists M>0 $ such that $\sqrt{((x^3+7)^2+(y^3+4)^2+3^2)}<M$ when $||(x,y)||<\delta$

From $||f(x,y)-f(0,0)||<||(x,y)-(0,0)||M$ for some $M>0$ continuity follows trivially.(Lipchitz function)